# Sending mail through Yahoo fails

Tags: email, vbscript

I have 2 (pretend) email addresses - Yahoo and Hotmail:
myyahoo@yahoo.com and myhotmail@hotmail.com (not real)

I am trying to send an email from Yahoo to Hotmail.

Basically I've tried several other email address configurations - all with no success.

I've been digging for a couple of days and the code below (modified from [here](http://webcheatsheet.com/asp/sending_email_asp.php)) SHOULD work, but it doesn't.

```
'Sending an email using a remote server
Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

'This section provides the configuration information for the remote SMTP server.

'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60

'If your server requires outgoing authentication, uncomment the lines below and use a valid email address and password.
'Basic (clear-text) authentication
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
'Your UserID on the SMTP server
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="myyahoo@yahoo.com"
'Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="password"

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update

'End of remote SMTP server configuration section

Mail.Subject="Email subject"
Mail.From="myyahoo@yahoo.com"
Mail.To="myhotmail@hotmail.com"
Mail.TextBody="This is an email message."

Mail.Send
Set Mail = Nothing
```

The error message is:

> Line  32
>   Char  1
>   Error The server rejected the sender address. The server response was 530 5.7.1 Authentication required
>   Code  8004020E
>   Source (null)

After a response from @Ansgar Wiechers I have modified the code.
I am absolutely sure that the dummy data (xxxx) is valid but I still get the same resulting error as above....

```
Set Mail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") ="smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="xxxx@yahoo.com"
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="xxxx"

Mail.Configuration.Fields.Update

Mail.Subject="Email subject"
Mail.From="xxxx@yahoo.com"
Mail.To="xxxx@hotmail.com"
Mail.TextBody="This is an email message."

Mail.Send
Set Mail = Nothing
```

Comment: Try enabling SSL (set `smtpusessl` option to `True`). Also make sure you use the correct server and port. It seems a bit odd that Yahoo should use port 25 for mail submission. Normally port 465 or 587 would be used.

Comment: Not sure which change smtpusessl or 465 did it but now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is rather self-explanatory. The remote server rejected your message, because it didn't authenticate correctly:

> Error The server rejected the sender address. The server response was 530 5.7.1 **Authentication required**

In your code the statement providing the password is commented out:

```
'Your UserID on the SMTP server
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") ="myyahoo@yahoo.com"
'Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") ="password"
```

so you're trying to authenticate with your mail address and an empty password. Uncomment that line and make sure the password is correct.

Also, you may need to enable SSL:

```
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://sche...tion/smtpusessl") = True
```

and/or change the port to 465 (smtps):

```
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://sche...tion/smtpserverport") = 465
```

or 587 (submission):

```
Mail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://sche...tion/smtpserverport") = 587
```

depending on what way of mail submission the server provides.

Comment: DOH!Thanks but as I expected the changes made absolutely no difference.

Comment: Thanks to @Ansgar Wiechers  I have taken out the comments and I'm absolutely sure there are no issues with the dummy data ('xxxx') but it still gives the same error message....         Not to sure how to use the formatting here so here is the revised code.....