# CDOSYS error '8004020e' sending to Yahoo

Tags: asp-classic

I am using CDOSYS for our asp classic mail.

OK, test mail with my yahoo account, and it sends out perfectly.
However, I use my clients email and password, and it gives an error '8004020e'.
I cannot figure out why it would be doing it. My client even had their password changed just to make sure that there was not a problem with the login information.

I will go back and use my yahoo email and password, and once again, it WORKS.
Just not with theirs.
Any idea's why it will work for one account but not for the other account?

Code below:

```
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") =MailServer
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 465
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = true 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60


' If your server requires outgoing authentication uncomment the lines bleow and use a valid email address and password.
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1 'basic (clear-text) authentication
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = emailAdd
myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = pass

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update
```

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937319/sending-mail-through-yahoo-fails

Comment: What sort of email server are you trying to send to.  If it's a MS Exchange server you probably need to use port 25

Comment: Sending to Yahoo Mail
So, it is all correct, we never figured it out.
We are now going a different rout, and using the domain email instead.
We have it setup, and all is working good now.

There is most likely something wrong with the email address, however, we never figured it out.

Comment: I would also like to add.
That since we are no longer working on trying to get this to work, that we no longer need any assistance on this issue.

Should we delete it, or leave it open?

Comment: Have you check this issue? http://gmsullivan.blogspot.hk/2010/05/fixing-asp-when-sending-from-server.html

Comment: That is the problem.
My Yahoo account set into the script, ran great.
However, putting my client's information in there, it errored out.
So, unfortunately, that link does not assist in this issue.
We no longer are using Yahoo, we are using the mail server from our hosting company to deal with the mail.

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually caused by one of the following

1. Incorrect SMTP server / port
2. Incorrect login/password
3. FROM address not valid according to SMTP server (wrong domain)

You've verified 1 & 2, so check #3

Comment: All is correct, so. Not really sure what the issue really is.
It is strange. We never figured it out.